# retrieving values from multiple columns in asp drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I've got a dropdown whose values are retrieved from a database. I am retrieving ID and name from the database.

```
public void GetDepartment_temp()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                listBoxDepartment.ClearSelection();
                Get_Department objDAL = new Get_Department();
                dt = objDAL.Get_Hospital_Department();
                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        listBoxDepartment.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["department_name"].ToString(), row["department_id"].ToString()));

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
```

I've got to show the number of employees of each department in the text box. Suppose a user selects human department, then the text box should display the number of employees in that department.

For the ListBox, only two values from the database can be retrieved. How can I show the number of employee in this condition?

```
public DataTable Get_Hospital_Department()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = DbAccessHelper.ExecuteDataSet("p_get_hospital_department", true).Tables[0];
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception) { return null; }
        }

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_get_hospital_department]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT department_id
        ,department_name
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_hospital_department];
END
```

Comment: Please share your code for `Get_Hospital_Department()`

Comment: I've provided the code and the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `For the ListBox, only two values from the database can be retrieved.` is not correct. You can populate the datatable with **as many fields as you want**. However, you can set only the Value and text attributes of the Listbox item as you have done.

1. Change the stored procedure code to fetch the employee count also.
2. Mark your datatable dt as `static and public`.
3. Fetch the datable and you can play with the data as you want. You can fetch the employee count in the textbox on listview selected index changed as shown below:

   ```
   public static DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   public void GetDepartment_temp()
   {
       try
       {


           string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SOConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
           SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);

           SqlCommand command =
               new SqlCommand(
                   "select  Department.DepartmentID, Department.[Department Name], count( Department.DepartmentID) as empCount from Department join Employee on Department.DepartmentID = Employee.DepartmentID group by Department.DepartmentID, Department.[Department Name]",
                   connection);

           command.Connection.Open();

           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
           da.Fill(dt);
           dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {dt.Columns["DepartmentID"]};
           ListBox1.ClearSelection();
           if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
           {
               foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
               {
                   ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["Department Name"].ToString(),
                       row["DepartmentID"].ToString()));

               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
       }
   }

   protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       DataRow dr = dt.Rows.Find(Convert.ToInt32(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value));
       TextBox5.Text = dr["empCount"].ToString();

   }
   ```